# Terminability of an algorithm and existence of an infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, set-theory

It is perfectly clear that when the familiar Gram-Schmidt algorithm is performed on a *finite* set of linearly independent vectors, the algorithm terminates and we get an orthogonal set of vectors. Fine.

Now they apply the algorithm to a countable set of linearly independent vectors in a Hilbert space recursively and get a countable orthogonal set of vectors. But the problem here is that this algorithm will *never* terminate, hence we cannot get the truly *infinite* collection of orthogonal vectors in finite time.

And now that I think about it, for any sequence that is defined via recursive relation (e.g. Fibonacci sequence), we shouldn't be able to write down a formal generating function because we don't have the truly infinite sequence!

So my question is: Does there exist an axiom in ZFC that allows me to say that there is truly an *infinite* collection satisfying the recursive relation?

Comment: Usually such problems can be solved by either power set axiom or replacement axiom (plus axiom of infinity, of course). For example power set gives you the set $\mathbb{R}^{<\omega}$ of all finite real sequences. Consider the subset $Y$ of all finite sequences that start with $0,1$ and satisfy the recurrence relation until wherever they end. Show by induction that $Y$ contains a unique sequence of each length (and therefore if $s\in Y$, any initial segment of $s$ is also in $Y$). Then $\bigcup Y$ is the desired infinite sequence (we regard a function as a set of ordered pairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf{ZFC}$ set theory proves the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a set,  let $X^{<\omega}$ denote the set of all finite sequences of elements of $X$ , let $[n]$ denote $\{0,1,2,…,n-1\}$ for $n\in \omega$. Suppose $g:X^{<\omega}\to X$ then there exists a unique function $f:\omega \to X$ such that $f(n)=g(f\restriction [n])$ for all $n \in 
> \omega $.

Defining $g:\mathbb{N}^{<\omega}\to \mathbb{N}$ as $0$ for sequences of length $0$, $1$ for sequences of length $1$, and $\sigma(n-1)+\sigma(n-2)$
for sequences, $\sigma$, of length $>2$. One gets that $f$ is the fibonacci sequence.

One can prove the theorem by building partial approximations and then gluing them up together to form a single function. Details can be found in any set theory book, e.g. Jech-Hrbáček, under the name of the "recursion theorem".

Infact $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can prove much stronger versions of this theorem, again details can be found in any introductory axiomatic set-theory book.

Comment: The second sentence of the theorem seems incomplete: $g$ should satisfy some hypothesis.

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry, I don't understand. I said that $g$ is a function from $X^{<\omega}\to X$. What is incomplete?

Comment: Okay, I had misunderstood the statement. I think a more natural hypothesis would be that there are partial functions $f_n\colon[n]\to X$ that satisfy compatibility conditions among them.